# How to find an element that has a specific child with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

I need to find all **tr** that has a **td** child with a specific bgcolor.

Is it possible with PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser?

I can get all **td** with the next sentence:

$cells = $html->find ( "tr td[bgcolor=#3366FF]" );

But I need the **tr** instead of the **td**. I don't know if it is possible to find ascendant elements.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

parent() should work.

```
foreach($html->find('td[bgcolor=#3366FF]') as $element) {
    $element->parent() etc...
```

This should work to have tr...

Comment: Yes, but if there are 3 **tr** and 35 **td**, for example, I will obtain 35 parents, and I only want to obtain the 3 **tr** to work with them.

Comment: You could perhaps search for all tr and test those which have at least one td[bgcolor=#3366FF] child ;)